# Parsing data using org.json

Tags: android, .net, json, serialization, org.json

(Please bear in mind I am completely new to Java and Android)

Having done a couple of tests I can see it is trivially easy to make a web service call in Android retrieve the results and using some simple custom code obtain the value.

For example:

```
Assuming a response string as such: {"d":"Hello World"}

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
String result = obj.getString("d");
//Result = Hello World
```

Great! This makes it easy enough to retrieve data using some custom code. However, this method becomes less trivial if you start using more complex data, such as an array that contains a custom class. Having come from a .NET background I am used to just marking a class as serializable and quickly being able to serialize and deserialize a class.

For example

```
public class Movie 
{
    public Movie() {}
    public String Title { get; set; }
    blah... blah...
}

public class MovieList : List<Movie> { }

public static void Serialize(String path, MovieList movieList)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MovieList));

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
       serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, movieList);
    }
}

public static MovieList Deserialize(String path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MovieList));
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        return (MovieList) serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
    }
}
```

I realize this is XML but you get my point... Either way I'm just wondering if there is a better way of accomplishing my goal then complete custom code using the org.json namespace?

Comment: You have this tagged as C#, not Java. Are you developing with MonoDroid (and hence the C# is a relevant tag), or are you developing in Java?

Comment: No developing in Java. Fair enough, probably shouldn't have marked it as a C# question... Ill change it now, or ur welcome 2.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now that we have language settled out... :-)

There is nothing built into Android for JSON-based serialization. However, there are third-party JSON libraries that can do this, such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Those that rely upon annotations may encounter some difficulties with Android, though.

Comment: I tried with a library called xStream or something? Anyways, I encountered performance issues but ill check those out. I guess I was hoping for something that was optimized for Android rather then just written in Java. I know Im asking for allot, lol.  Thank you...

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich: "I tried with a library called xStream or something? " -- that is for XML, not JSON. " was hoping for something that was optimized for Android rather then just written in Java" -- I am not quite certain what "optimized for Android" would mean in this context.

Comment: What I am saying is given my prior experiences (yes @ the time I was trying to serialize/deserialize XML - which probably was silly) was that it was unacceptably slow. Obviously I will have a look at these libraries and determine if they suffer from the same performance issues on an Android device. (My gut says, they may) My experience has been that libraries that are Java based don't always work as well on Android. That's assuming Android even has the libraries required to run the library.

Comment: i guess he means optimized for low memory footprint and low CPU usage.